# Excel Macro to copy a specific worksheet to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

this is my code for my Macro.  What is does is copy a specific sheet to another workbook. My question is how to paste only values and the format must be read type only.

```
Sub NewReport()
Dim PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE As Workbook
Dim PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC As Workbook

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE = ActiveWorkbook


Set PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE.Sheets(Array(PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE.Sheets(6).Name)).Copy _         
Before:=PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.Sheets(1)
PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\A3RBJZZ\Desktop\PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC"

PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.Close
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Format must be read type only'? 

To paste only values, use this - `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks :=False, Transpose:=False`

Comment: I use that code but it is not working, the format read type only is the attribute of excel so no one can edit the contents of it, thanks for the comment

Comment: Let say that the price_rev_template is Subject1 and the price_rev_template_fc is Subject2, Im sorry i just simplfy the code first when I paste in it. This is my first time to post in this site, hahah thank Bharath Raja for the concern

Answer (score 0):

Try this  - Hope this Helps

```
Sub NewReport()
   Dim PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE As Workbook
   Dim PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC As Workbook

   With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
   End With

   Set PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE = ActiveWorkbook


   Set PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
   PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE.Sheets(Array(PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE.Sheets(1).Name)).Copy Before:=PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.Sheets(1)

   'selecting all cells and pasting as only values
    PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Added the Readonlyrecommended attrib.
    PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\A3RBJZZ\Desktop\PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC", ReadOnlyRecommended:=True

    PRICE_REV_TEMPLATE_FC.Close
    With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .DisplayAlerts = True
      .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```